# JQuery Selector Doesn't Recognize String Created using JS Replace Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having problems running the following code snippet using JavaScript and JQuery.  listOfDisplayCategories is an array of String values.

When debugging using FireBug I can see that the value set in displayCategoryWithoutSpecialChar is the value that I expect.

When I try to use this value in the next statement as the selector for JQuery I don't see the behavior I expect.

Basically the value isn't recognized as a valid selector.  It doesn't fail or give an error, it just doesn't set the background image the way I'm expecting.

If I hardcode the value in the displayCategoryWithoutSpecialChar variable this works properly.  It seems like the value returned from this replace function doesn't work when I use it as the selector for JQuery.  Can anybody help me?

```
var displayCategoryWithoutSpecialChar = 
     listOfDisplayCategories[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "");
$("#"+displayCategoryWithoutSpecialChar).css("background-image","url(images/Aut.png)");
```

Comment: and also the HTML markup for the element that you want to change the css...

Comment: The first String in the array is "Auto/Building Tech". After the replace function I have "AutoBuildingTech". The following markup is the target of the css. <div id="AutoBuildingTech" class="category"><h1>Auto/Building Tech</h1><blockquote id="quote-0"><span>“</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit posuere<span>”</span></blockquote></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having is that the selector I was using was based on HTML that did not yet exist.  This code snippet was inside of a for loop that created HTML content.  The selector that I was attempting to specify was for html that was not yet a part of the document.  Moving the line with the selector and the CSS function after the HTML had been appended fixed the problem.  I debugged through the JQuery script to the point where document.getElementById(String) was invoked.  This call did not return an element.  I'm still unclear why hard-coding the string value allowed this to work.  Rookie mistake.